# Troubleshooting authentication configuration for multiple-login in Laravel 10

Tags: php, laravel

I am implementing manual multiple login functionality. There are three types of users: Customer, Seller, and Admin. Currently, I am testing the Customer login; however, I am encountering an error. Despite reading the Laravel Documentation and consulting with ChatGPT, the error persists. Could someone help me resolve this issue?

> Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::__construct(): Argument #2 ($provider)
> must be of type Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider, null given,
> called in
> /Users/yuto/18tha-gj_mall/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/AuthManager.php
> on line 127

**What I did**

1. Make 2 models Users/Customer and Users/Seller
2. Modified config/auth.php
3. Created a new function "authenticate" on Auth/LoginController

**Customer model**

```
namespace App\Models\Users;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticableTrait;

class Customer extends Model implements Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory, AuthenticableTrait;

    protected $fillable = [
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'email',
        'password',
        'payment_id',
    ];
}
```

**config/auth.php**

```
return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Defaults
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Guards
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | User Providers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    'providers' => [
        'customer' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\Users\Customer::class,
        ],

        'seller' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\Users\Seller::class,
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Resetting Passwords
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    'passwords' => [
        'customer' => [
            'provider' => 'customer',
            'table' => 'password_reset_tokens',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],

        'seller' => [
            'provider' => 'seller',
            'table' => 'password_reset_tokens',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Password Confirmation Timeout
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------

    */

    'password_timeout' => 10800,

];
```

**LoginController**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */

    public function authenticate(Request $request): RedirectResponse
    {
        $credentials = $request->validate([
            'email'    => ['required', 'email'],
            'password' => ['required'],
        ]);
    
        if (Auth::guard('customer')->attempt($credentials)) {
            $request->session()->regenerate();
            return redirect()->route('home');
        }
    
        if (Auth::guard('seller')->attempt($credentials)) {
            $request->session()->regenerate();
            return redirect()->route('home');
        }
    
        return back()->withErrors([
            'email' => 'The provided credentials do not match our records.',
        ])->onlyInput('email');
    }
}
```

Comment: there is no guard named `customer` or `seller` in `auth.php` ... your `web` guard is using a non-existing provider named `users`